# Serving Spring Rest docs

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I have the following Spring Rest Docs maven configuration, which makes my generated docs end up in `WEB-INF/classes/static/docs` when I package my Spring Boot app.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

then I'm trying to serve them up in this controller (`my-api-doc.html` is the name of the generated docs)

```
@Controller
public class DocsController {

    @RequestMapping("/docs")
    private String docs() {
        return "my-api-doc";
    }

}
```

But I am getting a 404. How can I make my Spring Boot app serve up the html from the WAR file in `WEB-INF/classes/static/docs`?

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was trying to serve the html from a controller. Files that end up in `WEB-INF/classes/static` are meant to be accessed directly and are not resolved when controllers look for a view. I was able to access the file directly with `my-api/docs/my-api-doc.html`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Boot docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot), static content should be in one of four predefined locations. `/WEB-INF/classes/static` is not one of them. Try moving your generated docs to `/public` or `/META-INF/resources`.

Comment: Tried changing it to both of these. It ends up not in the WAR at all when I do that

Comment: `/META-INF/resources` requires Servlet 3.0 app

Comment: `/WEB-INF/classes/static` is one of them. The blog post you've linked to shows that `classpath:/static/` is used and `WEB-INF/classes` is on the classpath when your application is packaged as a war file.

Answer (score -4):

Try using Swagger (at https://swagger.io/) for documentation. You can actually host the documentation of your APIs and get Updated automatically whenever you update the APIs(this reduces the burden of updating documentation whenever you made an update to APIs).
Also, the static folder is meant to attach View to Spring APIs, I suggest not to save any files in that.

Comment: Suggesting use of a completely different technology isn't an answer lol

Comment: Swagger, really? The question is how to serve api-documentation generated from Spring rest docs as static content from a spring boot app.